# How to get Screen metrics outside an Activity?

Tags: android

I have a Generic Pool that i am making here:

```
public class FruitPool extends GenericPool<Sprite> {
// ===========================================================
// Constants          
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================          
// Fields         
// =========================================================== 
private final TextureRegion mTextureRegion;
private Scene mScene;
// ===========================================================          
// Constructors          
// =========================================================== 
public FruitPool(final TextureRegion pFruitTextureRegion, Scene mScene2) {
    this.mTextureRegion = pFruitTextureRegion;
    this.mScene = mScene2;
}
// ===========================================================          
// Getter & Setter          
// =========================================================== 

// ===========================================================          
// Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces          
// ===========================================================  
@Override
protected Sprite onAllocatePoolItem() {
     Random rand = new Random();

        //I want to get the Screens Display metrics here...
    Sprite fruit = new Sprite(0, 0, this.mTextureRegion);

    mScene.attachChild(fruit);

    return fruit;

}
```

I am trying to get the screens display metrics like this..

```
    final Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    CAMERA_WIDTH = display.getWidth();
    CAMERA_HEIGHT = display.getHeight();
```

The only problem is, is that i cant figure out how to do this outside of an Activity..

Is this even possible? Or will i have to use SharedPreference or something?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to pass a Context to the FruitPool constructor. It could then retrieve the display metrics by calling `Context.getWindowManager()`. (If you want to run that code outside the constructor, save `context.getApplicationContext()`, in case it was passed an Activity context.)

EDIT: If you adopt this approach and are passing an `Activity` to the `FruitPool` object, and the lifetime of the `FruitPool` object might exceed the lifetime of the activity, then you *must not* keep a reference to the activity. You should instead keep a reference to `context.getApplicationContext()`. Since `getWindowManager()` is only defined for an `Activity`, you can instead use this expression to obtain the `WindowManager`:

```
(WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)
```

Comment: Great Answer! I never thought about that!

Comment: I tried this and it says that "The method getWindowManager() is undefined for the type Context"

Comment: pass Acticity object (this) instead of context . context is basically superclass of activity and probably getWindowManager() defined in Ativity class

Comment: @coder_For_Life22 D'oh. Sorry about that. Try `(WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)`.

Answer (score 109):

Despite the fact there is an accepted answer here, I'm posting another answer. The reasoning for this is the following. Passing contexts is not always a good idea imho, because in some cases (such as applied libraries, for example) contexts should not build additional and unnecessary dependencies from an application. The code is simple:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
```

It provides a solution for cases when known limitations of this method are not important for a developer. According to Android documentation:

> `getSystem()` returns a global shared Resources object that provides access to only system resources (no application resources), and is not configured for the current screen (can not use dimension units, does not change based on orientation, etc).

Anyway, all fields of `DisplayMetrics` are filled in with meaningful information. In my case, it was DPI which I was after. And the method provides me with DPI without a context.

Comment: I agree that this answer suites the question way better. Thanks @Stan

Comment: This also worked where I needed screen width in Layout.onMeasure(), and meant that the Android Studio Preview continued to work.

Comment: This will not always work, particularly on devices that support windowing and dynamically scaled displays. From [the docs for `Resources.getSystem()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getSystem&28%29) (emphasis added): "Return a global shared Resources object that provides access to only system resources (no application resources), and **is not configured for the current screen (can not use dimension units, does not change based on orientation, etc)**."

Comment: @TedHopp Your comment just repeats what I have already mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Yes, it does. The point of the comment is emphasis. Your answer has the disclaimer "for cases when known limitations of this method are not important". However the documentation specifically says that dimension units cannot be used and OP specifically wants dimension units. So when would it be the case that the limitations are unimportant?

Answer (score 7):

Here's another way to get the display metrics that ***is*** configured for the current screen.

`final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the api I have written to get the screen width, you need a context to get the window system service.
Similarly you can get the height.

```
int getWindowWidth() {
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    return size.x;
}
```